# Declaring a non-existing function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I try to understand how python works and I need a small explanation.
So I wrote a very short example and I have trouble understanding why it doesn't work.
I create a `test.py`:

```
def a():
    print('a() try to call non existing b()')
    b()
```

At this stage, if I write in a python shell

```
>>> import test
>>> test.a()
```

It doesn't work and it is normal because `b()` is unknown.
But when I write these following lines, it still not work.

```
>>> import test
>>> def b():
...     print('b()')
... 
>>> test.a()
```

A function in a python module can only call a function in the current module and imported modules ?

Comment: It can only call functions in its own module or modules that it imports.

Comment: A module shouldn't work differently depending on the script that imports it.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, so it is impossible to change the behavior of an existing function by redefining one ?

Comment: It's possible by modifying the module's dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to define `b()` within the same `test.py` where you defined `a()`.

It would work if you created a new python module (python file) where `b()` is defined and then imported that module into `test.py`

```py
from another_module import b # refers to function b

def a():
    print("this function calls b")
    b()
```

Something like the one above would work. Remember that the module that contains function `b()` and the `test.py` module should be in the same directory for it to work.

Comment: I understand, thank you. I thought on an interpreted language it might work, but no :)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! When you can mark it as the final answer for future visitors. Stay safe!!

Comment: Yes, I'm just waiting a little if some other people have other explanation or different way to explain. It could help more people maybe ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could redefine b

[How do I redefine functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692159/how-do-i-redefine-functions-in-python)

```
import test

def b():      # definition of b
  print('b()')

test.b = b  # function b redefined for test

test.a()   # now this works
```

Comment: It's what I tried to experiment :) So you can write module with functions that call non existing functions and declare the non existing function outside the module by an assignation :)

Comment: Yes.  It's normally used for overwriting existing functions [as this illustrates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829200/override-module-method-where-from-import-is-used) but no reason why the function needs to exists in the imported module.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve the behavior that I think you are describing by passing the function b into a as a parameter.

```
def a(b):
    print('called a')
    # Use the callable argument
    b()
def x():
    print('x')
a(x)
```

outputs:

```
called a
x
```